# Apple SSO: Random email address for user

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, tvos

I'm interested to implement Apple SSO through `AuthenticationService SDK` to my app, but there is a thing that bother me: Will Apple generate new random email address for user every time he use Apple SSO in my app? Or once user use Apple SSO, the generated random email address will always assigned to his real email address forever?

Please provide official document/statement from Apple if you have any answer for my question.

Thank you very much, guys!

Comment: When the user registers with your app, Sign In with Apple returns a unique identifier. You pass this identifier on subsequent authentication calls to ensure you get the same email address

Comment: @Paulw11 by unique identifier do you mean user ID generated by Apple SSO? and what do you mean by passing that identifier on subsequent authentication call, authentication in my app or to Apple?

Comment: Pass the [user](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aspasswordcredential/2968244-user) property of the credential to subsequent [authenticstion requests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidrequest/3153041-user)

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh okay, so you're saying the only property that has constant value among apps from a single developer is `user` which is user ID, right?

Comment: Not exactly. You provide that user id value (which is just an opaque string) to ensure that Apple gives you the previously associated user details.  You can share this property between your apps but not between apps from different developers. If you don't provide this value then you may get a new user association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is per app per Apple ID as far as I know. If user signs out, and later signs back in he will receive the same email address unless user has explicitly changed it in settings.

Check this out:
https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT210426#change

Comment: thanks for providing this useful info, this is the answer that I'm looking for.